# CSS: Font top margin

Tags: css, fonts, margin

I know the title of this question is stupid, but I couldn't come up with anything better. I have searched for hours on this topic, but either I search for something wrong, or else I have missed out on some CSS basics.

I have a container div with a 40x40px background-image placed in the top left corner. I want to align the top of the text from an h2 tag with the top of that background-image, which I have tried to do like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <h2 id="title">Lorem</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#container {
    background: url('test-icon.png') top left no-repeat;
    margin: 200px auto; /* To center the container on the page*/
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px; /* To prevent the text from "colliding with the background-image"*/
    width: 300px;
}

#title {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I have used Eric Meyers CSS reset to get rid of browser specific styles, but have left this out in the above code.

I have created a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/tomaslieberkind/e3fvq6wz/)

The problem is that the background-image and the top of the text from the h2-tag do not align - there is a small "margin" in the top of the h2 tag. This margin seems to change with the font size. When I use Google Chromes inspector, it tells me that the margin and padding of the h2 and div tag are all 0px. As browsers render fonts differently, I don't mant to mess around with negative margins in case it breaks the layout. Is there a way to "safely" get rid of this margin? To be totally clear, what I want to acheive is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2EiM.jpg).

Comment: +1, for a well asked question with code, a test case, and a goal image. It's rare.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the top position of the background image?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea - I will try that as well!

Comment: Could you re-post your example and goal image somewhere permanent? The links are broken now.

Comment: @LinusR Updated broken links.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your problem is the [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) on the `<h2>`. A bit of fiddling around tells me that you want it to be:

```
line-height: 10px;
```

You might need to use `px` for your `font-size` to get things to work consistently in various browsers.

Comment: That is precisely what I tried to acheive, but in a more generic way. As I read a bit more about fonts and line-height, I don't think this can be done without fiddling a bit around. Thanks.

Comment: The only time this fails is if the text needs to flow over >1 line, which was my problem when I found this question. Instead of reducing line-height, you can just use `position: relative; top: -0.3em;` or whatever it needs to be, but again this might be inconsistent across browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried line-height: 1; ?